# Is it possible to search for duplicated observations including the first announced using R

Tags: r, duplicates

My aim is to search for all duplicates of observations in a dataframe using R. the first column of my dataframe contains a character string of 15 numbers (observation-ID). some of these observation-IDs occur more then ones and contain diffrent information for the observed variables. I want to extract all duplicates (including the first one) into a new dataframe, so i can choose the most plausible one.

> duplicated() just extracts the second, third, ... observation that is duplicated
>   unique() extracts the first observation of duplicates. But maybe the first duplicate includes more information or is more plausible.

Comment: use `!unique()` for this

Comment: Can you provide an example to be more clear? If you know how to use a dplyr package then you can do ```data %>% group_by(observation-id) %>% tally``` and see for yourself how many duplicates there are.

Comment: duplicated(x) | duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE)

Comment: @ Richard Telford `duplicated(x) | duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE)` perfectly matched my needs. Thank you